# .NET Core 3.0 - Custom docker url being ignored

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-desktop

I need to have a docker container running with a specific custom url.

It needs to be the following:

```
localhost:9000/sample/
```

I have defined this in my launchsettings.json file:

```
 "Docker": {
        "commandName": "Docker",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/sample/",
        "publishAllPorts": true,
        "httpPort": 9000
    }
```

But when I run the container and launch it in the browser, it always leaves out 'sample', and looks like this:

```
localhost:9000
```

I tried using the following in launchsettiings.json instead:

```
 "Docker": {
        "commandName": "Docker",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "http://localhost:9000/sample/",
        "publishAllPorts": true,
        "httpPort": 9000
    }
```

But it still launches with just localhost:9000

What am I missing here?

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: try to change the launch url at `Run With>Custom Configuration > Run Action --> Debug .Net Core Debugger`

Answer (score 0):

In your startup.cs you can add the following line:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UsePathBase("/sample");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-3.0